# How use openalpr in java project

Tags: java, api, openalpr

I want to use openalpr in my java project. What must I include to use the API? What libs must be imported in project properties in Eclipse or Netbeans?

I found the solution

1. Download openalpr binaries
   https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/releases
2. Install and configure jdk (java and javac path)
3. Compile openalpr java source code, start java_test.bat file
4. Start main.java

   `java -classpath java Main "us" "openalpr.conf" "runtime_data" "samples/us-1.jpg"`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy the native libs (DLLs for windows) into the exec dir
2. Copy the java classes into your project (dir: /src/main/java)
3. Get started with:

`

```
Alpr alpr = new Alpr("us", "/path/to/openalpr.conf", "/path/to/runtime_data");

// Set top N candidates returned to 20
alpr.setTopN(20);

// Set pattern to Maryland
alpr.setDefaultRegion("md");

AlprResults results = alpr.recognize("/path/to/image.jpg");
System.out.format("  %-15s%-8s\n", "Plate Number", "Confidence");
for (AlprPlateResult result : results.getPlates())
{
    for (AlprPlate plate : result.getTopNPlates()) {
        if (plate.isMatchesTemplate())
            System.out.print("  * ");
        else
            System.out.print("  - ");
        System.out.format("%-15s%-8f\n", plate.getCharacters(), plate.getOverallConfidence());
    }
}
```

(Source: http://doc.openalpr.com/bindings.html#java)

Comment: from where should I copy the Java classes into my project? From where can I download the JARs I will need to develop an OPENALPR Java application for Ubuntu?

Comment: does it require licence ?

Comment: How would you check videos with this? The command line tool can do this too. But I didn't find a method in Java.